# Keeping Action Bar Hidden on ViewNavigator - Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a ViewNavigator that I want to hide the action bar. The creationComplete listener successfully removes the action bar, but as soon as another view is push, the action bar reappears. How can I keep it hidden?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           creationComplete="application1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            viewNav.hideActionBar(false);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pushView);
        }

        protected function pushView(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            viewNav.pushView(FirstView);
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="viewNav" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" firstView="FirstView" />
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`View` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html) has an `actionBarVisible` property. You can set this to `false` on each/all views, then it won't show up. Maybe I missed it, but I don't see a way to do it globally for the `ViewNavigator` itself, other than `hideActionBar()`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View actionBarVisible="false" >
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the hiding code inside the mouse handler?

```
    protected function pushView(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        viewNav.pushView(FirstView);
        viewNav.hideActionBar(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To globally hide the ActionBar just past this in your main application mxml or in your style file:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    s|View
    {
        actionBarVisible:false
    }
</fx:Style>
```